# SEO Website Alias optimisation

Tags: search, web, seo

I want to have a different alias for a part of my website, but are the results from that alias be considered part of the main website by the search engines ?
Today I have a forum in the main website www.example.com/forum/, the keywords are used by the SE for the ranking of www.example.com, but I'm need to replace that old forum, but don't want to kill the old one immediately, so I'm going to create forum.example.com.
But are the results from the forum alias be used by the search engines to grow the popularity of www.example.com, or will it just boost forum.example.com without any impact for the main ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it's my mistake I searched for the keyword Alias, but it's subdomain the right one.
I found what I was searching for http://www.webseoanalytics.com/blog/multiple-domains-vs-subdomains-vs-folders-in-seo/